# AEM inserts html info comment into json

Tags: json, aem

I have the following jsp

```
<%
    JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String parentNodePath = slingRequest.getRequestPathInfo().getResourcePath();
    String url = getServerBaseUrl(sling) + parentNodePath.split("/jcr:content")[0] + ".html?cid=twitter";
    UrlShortener urlShortener = sling.getService(UrlShortener.class);
    String shortUrl = urlShortener.shorten(url);
    String encShortUrl = URLEncoder.encode(shortUrl);
    jsonResult.put("url", url);
    jsonResult.put("shortUrl", shortUrl);
    jsonResult.put("encShortUrl", encShortUrl);
%>
<%=jsonResult.toString()%>
```

It executed when I type in browser the following adress http://servername:port/path/to/page.urlshortener.html.jsp

As you see i have "application/json" contentType. Result must contain only json information, but there is html comment:

```
{
    "url":"http://servername/content/app/test/test1/naps1.html?cid=twitter",
    "shortUrl":"http://servername/1E4sZYJ",
    "encShortUrl":"http%3A%2F%2Fservername%2F1E4sZYJ"
}
<!--
    cq{
        "decorated":false,
        "type":"app/components/page/newsarticlepage",
        "path":"/content/app/test/test1/naps1/jcr:content",
        "selectors":"urlshortener",
        "servlet": "Script/apps/app/components/page/contentpage/urlshortener.html.jsp","totalTime":276,"selfTime":276
    }
-->
```

Also i saw, this comments inserted after every component, or executed jsp in any page.
How to turn off insertion of this comment?

Comment: The comment is added for the authoring interface. They don't show up in publish. Add wcmmode=disabled as a query param to the end of your url and the comment should disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments `<!-- cq{ ... } -->` are added for the authoring interface. They are not included on the publish instance where wcmmode is disabled. You can see this by adding `wcmmode=disabled` as a query param to the end of your url. Also you will have to remove the `cf#` or `editor.html` from the url.

Comment: Also I found another solution: to use path/to/page/jcr:content.urlshortener.html instead of path/to/page.urlshortener.html in request url